# Android NDK Aborting

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk

I am trying to run a sample app with Android NDK. I am getting this one error which I am not able to figure out. I tried running other apps which work well. Please help!

Error: *** Android NDK: Aborting  . Stop. 
external location: C:\Users\snehamur\Documents\ndk\android-ndk-r9c\build\core\build-shared-library.mk

Comment: Did you setup NDK compilation?

Comment: What does the build log show above this _Error_? Is there something about `APP_BUILD_SCRIPT` or `NDK_PROJECT_PATH`?

Comment: This is displayed in my Console :
LOCAL_MODULE_FILENAME must not contain directory separators

Comment: Could you share your Android.mk file?